# WiX installer leaves empty folders for custom actions

Tags: wix, custom-action

I've created a WiX installer project and a CustomAction project. I've successfully added the MyCustomAction to the installation script and it works as it should.

However, the installer leaves empty folders in the `[INSTALLFOLDER]` every time the installer is executed. They're named `MyCustomAction.CA.dll-`, `MyCustomAction.CA.dll-0`, `MyCustomAction.CA.dll-1` etc. Even the uninstaller won't remove them, so the amount of empty folders just get bigger.

Is there a way to prevent the folder creation? I've tried different Execute values (commit, deferred) but they don't seem to make any difference.

MyCustomAction is defined as follows:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyCustomAction"
              Return="check"
              Execute="commit"
              FileKey="MyCustomAction.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="MyCustomAction" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Please share the directory structure and provide the project location and your install location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem: I had included the `MyCustomAction.CA.dll` in my product's installation files and not in its own Fragment. That caused the dll to be copied to the installation folder.

Now when the CustomActions are defined in their own Fragment the temporary folder is not created in the INSTALLFOLDER.

Answer (score 0):

did you add a binary entry for them?

```
<Binary Id='FooBinary' SourceFile='foo.dll'/>
```

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html